# Fazendo validação de array dentro de outro array

Tags: php, array, if, foreach

Eu tenho o seguinte `array`, quando dou um `var_dump()`:

```
array(2) {
  [""]=>
  array(10) {
    ["js/ultramegamenu.js"]=>
    string(19) "js/ultramegamenu.js"
    ["js/padoo/jquery.cycle.js"]=>
    string(24) "js/padoo/jquery.cycle.js"
    ["js/jquery.mask.js"]=>
    string(17) "js/jquery.mask.js"
    ["js/smartheader.js"]=>
    string(17) "js/smartheader.js"
    ["js/stickyheader.js"]=>
    string(18) "js/stickyheader.js"
    ["js/app.js"]=>
    string(9) "js/app.js"
    ["js/carousel/script.js"]=>
    string(21) "js/carousel/script.js"
    ["js/lazyload.js"]=>
    string(14) "js/lazyload.js"
    ["js/script.js"]=>
    string(12) "js/script.js"
    ["js/plumrocket/pslogin/pslogin.js"]=>
    string(32) "js/plumrocket/pslogin/pslogin.js"
  }
  ["defer"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["js/tm/ajaxsearch/xregexp-all.js"]=>
    string(31) "js/tm/ajaxsearch/xregexp-all.js"
    ["js/tm/ajaxsearch.js"]=>
    string(19) "js/tm/ajaxsearch.js"
  }
}
```

Com o seguinte código abaixo, eu tento fazer a comparação onde, caso o valor da posição for igual a `string`, que no caso seria o diretório do meu `script`, ele executaria o mesmo(o `var_dump()` que dou no código é o que está sendo exibido acima).

```
foreach ($lines as $if => $items) {
    if (empty($items)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (!empty($if)) {
        // open !IE conditional using raw value
        if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
            $html .= $if . "\n";
        } else {
            $html .= '<!--[if '.$if.']>' . "\n";
        }
    }

    // static and skin css
    $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%s"%s />'."\n",
        empty($items['js_css']) ? array() : $items['js_css'],
        empty($items['skin_css']) ? array() : $items['skin_css'],
        $shouldMergeCss ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedCssUrl') : null
    );

    var_dump($items['skin_js']);

    foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['name'];
    }
    if (($items['skin_js'] == "js/tm/ajaxsearch/xregexp-all.js") || ($items['skin_js'] == "js/tm/ajaxsearch.js") || ($items['skin_js'] == "js/jquery.mask.js")) {
        echo "Entrou";
        $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"%s></script>' . "\n",
            empty($items['js']) ? array() : $items['js'],
            empty($items['skin_js']) ? array() : $items['skin_js'],
            $shouldMergeJs ? null : null
        );
    } else{
        // static and skin javascripts
        $html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"%s></script>' . "\n",
            empty($items['js']) ? array() : $items['js'],
            empty($items['skin_js']) ? array() : $items['skin_js'],
            $shouldMergeJs ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedJsUrl') : null
        );
    }

    // other stuff
    if (!empty($items['other'])) {
        $html .= $this->_prepareOtherHtmlHeadElements($items['other']) . "\n";
    }

    if (!empty($if)) {
        // close !IE conditional comments correctly
        if (strpos($if, "><!-->") !== false) {
            $html .= '<!--<![endif]-->' . "\n";
        } else {
            $html .= '<![endif]-->' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

O problema é que ele não está entrando dentro do `if`, assim, não está sendo executado corretamente.

Comment: O problema do seu código é que você está comparando um array com uma string, no seu caso sempre será falso. $items['skin_js'] é um vetor de um vetor, para acessá-lo você deve usar `$items["skin_js"][""]["js/tm/ajaxsearch/xregexp-all.js"]` ou `$items["skin_js"]["defer"]["js/tm/ajaxsearch/xregexp-all.js"]`, assim você conseguirá ter acesso a String dentro do vetor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `if` funcionará corretamente se você fizer da seguinte maneira:

```
foreach ($items['skin_js'] as $value) {
    if (( $value["js/tm/ajaxsearch/xregexp-all.js"] != null ) || ($value["js/tm/ajaxsearch.js"] != null) || ($value["js/jquery.mask.js"] != null)) {
            echo "Entrou";
            ...
        } else{
            // static and skin javascripts
            ...
        }
}
```

O `foreach` inicial varrerá os dois elementos do seu vetor `[""]` e `["defer"]` e o `$value` é o array contido nessas chaves. É realizada a verificação se contém algum elemento para chave especificada. Como a chave e o valor são iguais, não foi necessário verificar se `$value["js/tm/ajaxsearch/xregexp-all.js"] == "js/tm/ajaxsearch/xregexp-all.js"` por exemplo. Só foi considerado se o valor da posição não era vazia.

Comment: Deu certo! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Muito obrigado por toda ajuda e atenção!